# Combine Filter with Distinct function

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, formula

Power Apps question:

Input: Our SharePoint list:

| Team | InvoiceNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft | 2002 |
| Microsoft | 2002 |
| Google | 2003 |
| Google | 2003 |

There could be few records in the table related to 'InvoiceNumber'.

1st of all, what I already did, so you could see the whole picture.
On startup screen I use function: `Sort(Distinct(Table01,Team),Result,Ascending)`.

Result is:

|  |
| --- |
| Microsoft |
| Google |

Then, there is a arrow button with: `Set(VariableTeam, ThisItem.Result); Navigate(Screen1)`

On 'Screen1' a gallery:

`Filter(Table1, Team = VariableTeam)`

Result is (if we make transition from Microsoft):

|  |
| --- |
| 2002 |
| 2002 |

**Question**:

How to combine Distinct function with my filter to see "InvoiceNumber" as unique entry in App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in Power apps:

```
Distinct(Filter(Table1, Team = VariableTeam), InvoiceNumber)
```

**Documentation**: [Distinct function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-distinct)

Comment: Damn, I didn't expect it's going to be that simple, cuz I started to combine two formulas into something weird. Thanks a lot! 

Solved.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!